# How many composite pairs $(6n-1, 6n+1)$ in the range $[5, 6(1+35t)+1]$ for large $t$

Tags: number-theory

I would like to find out that how many composite pairs $(6n-1,\, 6n+1)$ are their     in the range $[5, 6(1+35t)+1]$ for large $t$.  Total composite pairs should be a function of t.  For example, there are t composite pairs  such that 6n = 1 Mod 5, 6n = -1Mod 7.

Comment: how large is $t$?

Comment: Presumably, you are looking for an estimate.

Comment: write a program and find it out

Comment: this problem can solve a PC

Comment: (5,7) , (11,12) ,.., (6(1+35t)-1 ,6(1+35t) )  There are 1+35t pairs

Comment: @mahdokht: composite pairs. So, (5,7), for example, has to be excluded.

Comment: @mathlove Sorry.